# Angular 6, scroll to top

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, scrollto

I have come across an issue in my angular 6 application. When the route is appended, the scroll doesn't change its position. I want it to scroll to the top of the page when the route gets appended.
    `http://localhost:4200/#/pending-transfer` is the initial route. After the user clicks on a button in the page, the route gets appended to `http://localhost:4200/#/pending-transfer/2595/62`.
I have tried using `window.scrollTo(0,0)` in `ngOnInit()`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Try it in `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: Hey @Ramya, the links you used in your question only point to your local machine. To help us answer your question, can you post some of your code for us to look at to get a better idea of what's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Angular v6 or more, You can simply set this option in extra options of routing configuration like below -

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
         scrollPositionRestoration: 'top'
      })
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

This will always set your scroll position to top while navigation.

For more in details see here -

- [Deep dive into Angular Routing — Scrolling to top, Debugging and lot more](https://medium.com/@PardeepJain/deep-dive-into-angular-routing-scrolling-to-top-debugging-and-lot-more-a995c08498d3)

Answer (score 2):

if you are using angular material side nav component then use below code:

```
const element = document.querySelector('mat-sidenav-content') || window;
element.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, none of the others worked for me with Angular Material.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue a while back, and this worked for Angular 4. Hopefully, you can use it too. This is in *app.component.ts*:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private location: Location) { }

  private lastPoppedUrl: string;
  private yScrollStack: number[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    const path = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['path'];
    const navigateTo = '/' + path;

    if (path) {
      this.router.navigate([navigateTo]);
    }

    this.location.subscribe((ev: PopStateEvent) => {
      this.lastPoppedUrl = ev.url;
    });

    this.router.events.subscribe((ev: any) => {
      if (ev instanceof NavigationStart) {
        if (ev.url != this.lastPoppedUrl)
          this.yScrollStack.push(window.scrollY);
      } else if (ev instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        if (ev.url == this.lastPoppedUrl) {
          this.lastPoppedUrl = undefined;
          window.scrollTo(0, this.yScrollStack.pop());
        } else
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      }
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if the approach I took is correct or not. But, instead of window.scrollTo(0,0), I wrote goTop.scrollTo(0,0), where goTop is a variable which stores the element which is at the topmost position in the page.                                                                                                                                           var goTop = document.getElementById("scrollPos");
goTop.scrollTo( 0 , 0);

Answer (score 0):

app.component.ts insert this code

```
    export class AppComponent {
  
  isShow: boolean;
  topPosToStartShowing = 100;

  @HostListener('window:scroll')
  checkScroll() {
      
    const scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;

    console.log('[scroll]', scrollPosition);
    
    if (scrollPosition >= this.topPosToStartShowing) {
      this.isShow = true;
    } else {
      this.isShow = false;
    }
  }

  gotoTop() {
    window.scroll({ 
      top: 0, 
      left: 0, 
      behavior: 'smooth' 
    });
  }
}
```

Then open on app.component.html
create button to top
example code :

```
    <button class="button" *ngIf="isShow" (click)="gotoTop()">
Top ↑ </button>
```

Comment: Can you explain the code you have posted? Answers which are code-only usually do not help people that much.